# Command Prompt Server/Client Error 1825 a security package specific error occurred

Tags: command-prompt, rpc

I am trying to message my friend through command prompt as a simple exercise but it has turned out to be quite complicated. I am running XP which has NET but must use `MSG.EXE` to communicate with his Windows 8 computer. We set `AllowRemoteRPC` to *true* and `fDenyTSConnection` to *false* but now we have an `error 1825: a security package specific error occurred`. How can I fix this?

The line of code I am using is as follows:

```
 msg server:/servername message
```

We are connected through a VLAN if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.exe /?` gives next syntax hints:

```
  MSG username [options] [message]
  MSG sessionname [options] [message]
  MSG sessionid   [options] [message]
  MSG  @filename [options] [message]
  MSG * [options] [message]
```

E.g. to send a message to all sessions on the server, your line of code should be as follows:

```
msg * /server:servername message
```

Edit:

1. *We set `AllowRemoteRPC` to **true** and `fDenyTSConnection` to **false*** but both registry values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server` should be  of `REG_DWORD` type and set to `1` and `0` respectively.
2. I don't know whether matters or not: there is an information about `CIMOM` settings [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854(v=vs.85).aspx): value `AllowAnonymousCallback` (`REG_DWORD` type, set to `1` or `0`) under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM` key: the CIMOM settings need to be updated if the remote connection is between computers that do not have a trust relationship; otherwise, an asynchronous connection will fail. This setting should not be modified for computers in the same domain or in trusted domains...

Comment: Still got the same error message. It doesn't really matter how I set up the command, there is some underlying error; the command is correct but something else is interfering I'm fairly certain.

Answer (score 0):

windows 7 ultimate and professional has msg support.
as windows vista.
in windows 7 ultimate( i tested it). you need to have credential on  the receiving pc. probably all after windows 7.
and...
of course change  both register mentioned at this forum.
next is from other forum... 
Expert Commentby:amorales63
ID: 343786552010-12-17
This seemed like as good a place as any to pass this along.

I have been getting "Error [1722]: RPC sever is not available" when using msg.exe to send messages to Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008. It would work to XP and Server 2003 FROM Windows 7 and Server 2008. Everything I read here and other places said it should work and it didn't. I had the following:

AllowRemoteRPC set to 1 - was already set
Firewall off - I'm on a domain behind a firewall
Enable File and Printer Sharing - was off, enabling didn't fix it
Enable Network Discovery - was off, enabling didn't fix it.
The Windows 7 PC I was testing with didn't have AV running, don't know about another Windows 7 PC or the Server 2008
Starting RPC Locator - was not running, starting it didn't fix it.

So I started comparing registry entries between the XP and Windows 7 PCs. There is a value fDenyTSConnections for the Terminal Server in the same path as AllowRemoteRPC. The XP PC had this as 0 by default. The Windows 7 and Server 2008 PCs had this a 1 by by default. Changing it to 0 got it to work on both PCs. This probably applies to any O/S after Vista.

Hope this keeps somebody else from going crazy like it did me for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be your OS Username contains Space in between which can lead to Error 1825 or Error 5.

Try removing Space from username it will work fine.